# Recovering $z_1,z_2\in\mathbb{C}$ from their modulus and $\mathrm{Re}(z_1z_2), \ \mathrm{Im}(z_1z_2)$

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers

Let $z_1,z_2\in\mathbb{C}$ arbitrary but fixed. Now, consider $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4\in\mathbb{R}$ given by $$
x_1:=\mathrm{Re}(z_1z_2), \quad x_2:=\mathrm{Im}(z_1z_2), \quad x_3:=\vert z_1\vert^2+\vert z_2\vert^2, \quad x_4:=\vert z_1\vert^2-\vert z_2\vert^2.
$$
My question is, if I know $x_1,...,x_4$, can I completely recover $z_1$ and $z_2$ as functions of $x_1,...,x_4$? I've been trying to do some algebraic manipulations but I have't suceed in completely identifying $z_1$ and $z_2$. Clearly, from $x_3\pm x_4$ we can recover the modulus of $z_1$ and $z_2$, but I am not sure how to obtain their argument (their phase in the complex plane). Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, because $z_1,\,z_2\mapsto e^{i\theta}z_1,\,e^{-i\theta}z_2$ preserve the $x_j$ for all $\theta\in\Bbb R$. In polar coordinates, write $z_j=r_je^{it_j}$ so $r_1=\sqrt{\tfrac{x_3+x_4}{2}},\,r_2=\sqrt{\tfrac{x_3-x_4}{2}},\,r_1r_2\exp i(t_1+t_2)=x_1+ix_2$ to show this is the most general underdeterminarion of the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: compute $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$, $x_4$ for the following two pairs $(z_1, z_2)$:
$$
z_1 = 1,\; z_2 = -1 \\
z_1 = z_2 = i \\
$$